# Create a graph using GraphX in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, named-entity-recognition, word-sense-disambiguation

I am trying a simple example but I am unable to use the Graph API to generate a graph using the following code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GGenerate").setMaster("local").set("spark.cores.max", "10");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
List<Tuple2<Long,String>> l1=new ArrayList<Tuple2<Long, String>>();
l1.add(new Tuple2<Long, String>(1L,"Alice"));
l1.add(new Tuple2<Long, String>(2L, "Bob"));
l1.add(new Tuple2<Long, String>(3L, "Charlie"));
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Long,String>> vert=context.parallelize(l1);

List<Tuple3<Long,Long,String>> rd=new ArrayList<Tuple3<Long,Long,String>>();
rd.add(new Tuple3(1L,2L,"worker"));
rd.add(new Tuple3(2L, 3L, "friend"));
JavaRDD<Tuple3<Long, Long, String>> edge=context.parallelize(rd);
```